# Change this code from FileReader() to URL.createObjectURL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see this particular code everywhere on Stackoverflow and many suggested that it needs to be converted from `FileReader()` to `URL.createObjectURL` Doing so will make it faster and the links will be shorter. But I have yet to find a working solution. (It's an image preview script that shows image thumbs on upload).

Can somebody help me convert it?

```
<script>

    $(window).load(function(){

    function readURL() {
        var $input = $(this);
        var $newinput =  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.portimg ');
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                reset($newinput.next('.delbtn'), true);
                $newinput.attr('src', e.target.result).show();
                $newinput.after('<div class="delbtn delete_upload"  title="Remove"><span class="bbb-icon bbb-i-remove2"></span></div>');


$("form").on('click', '.delbtn', function (e) {
    reset($(this));

  });
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $(".file").change(readURL);


    function reset(elm, prserveFileName) {
        if (elm && elm.length > 0) {
            var $input = elm;
            $input.prev('.portimg').attr('src', '').hide();

            if (!prserveFileName) {
                $($input).parent().parent().parent().find('input.file ').val("");
                //input.fileUpload and input#uploadre both need to empty values for particular div
            }
            elm.remove();
        }
    }

    });

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you mean correctly, you may want to use [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) function like this:

```
// your url will look like this
// blob:http://example.com/a298356a-ad76-4353-a35f-b6e22a0e792f
var url = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
```

Full code:

```
function readURL() {
    var $input = $(this);
    var $newinput =  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.portimg ');
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

        reset($newinput.next('.delbtn'), true);
        $newinput.attr('src', url).show();
        $newinput.after(`
            <div class="delbtn delete_upload"  title="Remove">
                <span class="bbb-icon bbb-i-remove2"></span>
            </div>
        `);

        $("form").on('click', '.delbtn', function (e) {
            reset($(this));
        });
    }
}
```